# How to create a dataset in VS for SSRS 2008 report with MySQL data, via openquery and linked server

Tags: mysql, sql, reporting-services

I have successfully created a linked server in SQL Server 2005 to MySQL database.  I need to call/execute a MySQL stored procedure from VS (to refresh table data in MySQL) and then create a dataset with this data for a report in SSRS 2008.

I can run the following from a SSMS query window without issue:

```
select * from openquery(myLinkedSrvrname,'call myMySQLprocname')
```

However I cannot get this statement to run from the Query Designer window within VS to create a dataset.  It produces a syntax error.  Can anyone suggest a fix for the above openquery statement or know how to execute a MySQL stored procedure from Reporting Services to create a dataset?

**Error Code**

> An error occurred while executing the query. ERROR[42000][MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver][mysqld-5.5.16]. 
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
>   the the manual that corresponds to your MySQL Server version for the right syntax to use near ('myLinkedSrvrname, 'myMySQLprocname')' at line 1

Comment: What is the text of the error?

Comment: An error occurred while executing the query.  ERROR[42000][MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver][mysqld-5.5.16].  You have an error in your SQL syntax; the the manual that corresponds to your MySQL Server version for the right syntax to use near ('myLinkedSrvrname, 'myMySQLprocname')' at line 1.

Comment: Sounds like you're connecting directly from SSRS to MySQL, rather than going through the MS SQL -> MySQL link. Is the Data Source your MS SQL server or your MySQL server? If it's MySQL, have you tried changing your dataset type in SSRS to "stored procedure" and simply naming it, rather than using any openquery-style function?

Comment: I've tried to call the procedure as both a text string and as a stored procedure with no luck.

Comment: do you have a SQL Server Database set up?

Comment: I guess a better question would be, "have you found a solution to your problem yet?"

Answer (score 1):

You can either 
1) create  a connection directly from SSRS (requires an ODBC connection on the SSRS server as well as on your dev machine) http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/

or

2) you can wrap this openquery MySQL call inside a SQL Server stored proc. That will enable you to then pass a parameter from the report to the SQL Server stored proc and then on to the MySQL Stored proc. It requires the use of Dynamic SQL inside the SQL Server proc however.

If you go with the first option you might then be able to call the Stored Proc directly, but I've only done that with an Oracle connection which is not via ODBC, so SSRS might grey that option out.

Using the second option you might run into further problems with 2-hop authentication, depending on what server operating systems you are running. Calling the MySQL proc from SSMS is only 1 hop so wouldn't present that problem.

Edit: Apparently it's possible to add the MySQL ADO.NET connector to SSRS:
[http://www.mazsoft.com/blog/post/2010/11/04/Using-SQL-Server-2008-Reporting-Services-(SSRS)-with-MySQL.aspx](http://www.mazsoft.com/blog/post/2010/11/04/Using-SQL-Server-2008-Reporting-Services-%28SSRS%29-with-MySQL.aspx)

Sounds complex but if you do a lot of MySQL it would be better than using ODBC.